# In KDE, how can I automatically tell which "Desktop" a Konsole terminal is in?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma

I have multiple "desktops" that I switch between for different tasks in my KDE Linux environment.  How can I automagically determine which desktop my Konsole ( kde console) window is being displayed in?

EDIT:
I'm using KDE 3.4 in a corporate environment

This is programming related.  I need to programatically (a.k.a. automagically ) determine which desktop a user is on and then interact with X windows in that desktop from a python script.

Should I go around and nuke all Microsoft IDE questions as not programming related?  How about Win32 "programming" questions?  Should I try to close those too?

Comment: Why are you trying to determine this? What will you do with the result once you find it? Without knowing that, the best answer is "Click the konsole button on your taskbar, and see what desktop it switches to."

Comment: at least some info is required. kde4, kde3? what konsole version?

Comment: I need to determine the desktop in code, not by asking a user to tell me which desktop they're on.

Comment: Konsole uber alles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dcop, the kde Desktop COmmunication Protocol, you could easily get current desktop executing

```
  dcop kwin KWinInterface currentDesktop
```

command. If you are working with new kde 4.x dcop is no more used, and you can translate the command to a DBUS call. It should be quite simple to send/get dbous messages with python apis.

Sorry for my bad english,
Emilio

Comment: Finally found a KDE/Gnome-agnostic version of the above command.  It is `xprop -root | egrep '^_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP'`

Comment: dcop is now out of date; instead of dcop you might want to use dbus.  See my alternate answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Actually **EWMH** `_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP` gives you which is the current desktop for X, not relative to the application. Here's a C snippet to get the `_WM_DESKTOP` of an application. If run from the KDE Konsole in question it will give you what desktop it is on, even it is not the active desktop or not in focus.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Shell.h>
...

Atom net_wm_desktop = 0;
long desktop;
Status ret;

/* see if we've got a desktop atom */
Atom net_wm_desktop = XInternAtom( display, "_NET_WM_DESKTOP", False);
if( net_wm_desktop == None ) {
    return;
}

/* find out what desktop we're currently on */
if ( XGetWindowProperty(display, window, net_wm_desktop, 0, 1, 
            False, XA_CARDINAL, (Atom *) &type_ret, &fmt_ret, 
            &nitems_ret, &bytes_after_ret, 
            (unsigned char**)&data) != Success || data == NULL
) {
fprintf(stderr, "XGetWindowProperty() failed");
    if ( data == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No data returned from XGetWindowProperty()" );
    }
    return;
}
desktop = *data;
XFree(data);
```

and `desktop` should be the index of the virtual desktop the Konsole is currently in. That is not the same which head of a multi-headed display. If you want to determine which head, you need to use `XineramaQueryScreens` (Xinerama extension, not sure if there is a XRandR equivalent or not. Does not work for nVidia's TwinView.

Here's an excerpt from some code I wrote, that given a x and y, calculate the screen boundaries (sx, sy, and sw with screen width and sh for screen height). You can easily adapt it to simply return which "screen" or head x and y are on. (Screen has a special meaning in X11).

```
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xinerama.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

Bool xy2bounds(Display* d,int x, int y, int* sx, int* sy, int* sw, int* sh) {
   *sx = *sy = *sw = *sh = -1;   /* Set to invalid, for error condition */
   XineramaScreenInfo *XinInfo;
   int xin_screens = -1;
    int i;
   int x_origin, y_origin, width, height;
   Bool found = False;

   if ( d == NULL )
      return False;
   if ( (x < 0) || (y < 0) )
      return False;

   if ( True == XineramaIsActive(d) ) {
      XinInfo = XineramaQueryScreens( d, &xin_screens );
      if ( (NULL == XinInfo) || (0 == xin_screens) ) {
         return False;
      }
   } else {
      /* Xinerama is not active, so return usual width/height values */
      *sx = 0;
      *sy = 0;
      *sw = DisplayWidth( d, XDefaultScreen(d) );
      *sh = DisplayHeight( d, XDefaultScreen(d) );
      return True;
   }

   for ( i = 0; i < xin_screens; i++ ) {
      x_origin = XinInfo[i].x_org;
      y_origin = XinInfo[i].y_org;
      width = XinInfo[i].width;
      height = XinInfo[i].height;
      printf("Screens: (%d) %dx%d - %dx%d\n", i,
            x_origin, y_origin, width, height );

      if ( (x >= x_origin) && (y >= y_origin) ) {
         if ( (x <= x_origin+width) && (y <= y_origin+height) ) {
            printf("Found Screen[%d] %dx%d - %dx%d\n",
               i, x_origin, y_origin, width, height );

            *sx = x_origin;
            *sy = y_origin;
            *sw = width;
            *sh = height;
            found = True;
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   assert( found == True );

   return found;
}
```

Comment: I'm working my way through your example code, but I can't figure out how to get a "Window" handle to the Konsole window?

Comment: I had forgotten that detail, but it should be possible with `xwininfo` or `xprop`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the other answers give current desktop, not desktop of terminal of script. @mctylr I added an answer that does it using xprop.

Answer (score 5):

Referring to the accepted answer.... dcop is now out of date; instead of dcop you might want to use dbus (qdbus is a command line tool for dbus).

```
qdbus org.kde.kwin /KWin currentDesktop
```

Comment: With KDE 5.12 on Kubuntu 18.04, it is `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin currentDesktop`.

Answer (score 3):

The KDE window manager, as well as GNOME and all WMs that follow the [freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/) standards support the [Extended Window Manager Hints](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2505544) (EWMH).

These hints allow developers to access programmatically several window manager functions like maximize, minimize, set window title, virtual desktop e.t.c

I have never worked with KDE but Gnome provides such functionality so I assume that KDE has it too.

It is also possible to access a subset of these hints with pure [Xlib](http://tonyobryan.com/index.php?article=9) functions. This subset are [ICCCM](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/) hints. If memory serves me correct virtual desktop access is only in EWMH.

Update: [Found](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s03.html) it! (`_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP`)

Answer (score 2):

A new answer because MOST of the answers here get the current desktop, not the one the terminal is in (Will break if user changes desktop while script is running).

`xprop -id $WINDOWID | sed -rn -e  's/_NET_WM_DESKTOP\(CARDINAL\) = ([^)]+)/\1/pg'`

I tested this in a loop while changing desktops, it works ok (test script bellow, you have to check the output manually after the run).

```
while true
do
  xprop -id $WINDOWID | sed -rn -e  's/_NET_WM_DESKTOP\(CARDINAL\) = ([^)]+)/\1/pg'
  sleep 1
done
```

Thanks for the other answers and comments, for getting me half way there.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing, but with one more restriction, I don't want to run a shell command to achieve the result. Starting from Kimball Robinson answer, this is what I got.

Tested working in Python3.7, Debian 10.3, KDE Plasma 5.14.5.

```
import dbus 

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
proxy = bus.get_object("org.kde.KWin", "/KWin")
int( proxy.currentDesktop(dbus_interface="org.kde.KWin") )
```