# In KDE4, how can I automatically tell which “Desktop” a Konsole terminal is in?

Tags: shell, kde-plasma, kde4

I was looking for this and found a [question and answer for KDE3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738059/in-kde-how-can-i-automatically-tell-which-desktop-a-konsole-terminal-is-in); I figured more people will be interested in the answer for KDE4 as time passes (posting here just so I can also post the answer...)

Answer (score 1):

`qdbus org.kde.kwin /KWin org.kde.KWin.currentDesktop` prints the number of the current virtual desktop.